# java collections and errorlist mixed problems

Tags: java, collections

im trying to devide two arrays what im trying to do is one list contains some striings and the second list contains some other strings ex:list 1 have **qw,we,er,rt,ty** and list2 have **we,er** when i divide list1 from list2 the output should be --**qw,rt,ty** heres my code

```
package Arraylist;

import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Charith
 */
public class arList {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String word[] = {
            "Hello", "Funny", "Bunny", "Honey"
        };
        List < String > l1 = new ArrayList < String > ();

        for (String s: word) {
            l1.add(s);
        }



        String deleteWord[] = {
            "Funny", "Bunny"
        };
        List < String > l2 = new ArrayList < String > ();

        for (String r: deleteWord) {
            l2.add(r);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", l1.get(i));
        }


        editlist(l1, l2);
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", l1.get(i));
        }


        * * public static void editlist(Collection < String > list1, Collection < String > list2) * * {
            Iterator < String > it = list1.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                if (list2.contains(it.next()))
                    it.remove();
            }


        }

    }
}
```

but i get an error on line **public static void editlist(Collection list1,Collection list2)** can someone tell me how to correct that error and can someone explain me what is **Collection**s in java i google it but its really confusing

Comment: In future, rather than just telling us where you're getting the error, why don't you tell us *what* the error is? Additionally, fix your indentation to make your question easier to read... and ideally, as a matter of style, use `Foo[] array` instead of `Foo array[]`. Either will work, but the first is more idiomatic in Java.

Comment: Also, there's a nice function Arrays.asList, let's you get those constant lists set up easily and clearly:  List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("Funny","Bunny");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at where your method declaration comes. It's directly after this:

```
for(int i =0;i<l1.size();i++){
    System.out.printf("%s " ,l1.get(i));
}
```

In other words, it's still part of the `main` method. You need an extra closing brace to finish the `main` method before you can declare a new method. You can't declare one method instead another (aside from for inner classes, which you're not using here).

There are also much better ways of achieving what you want, but that's a different matter - as Priyank's answer states, `removeAll` would be a simpler approach.

Comment: thanks for the help and is there a good explenation about collection class rather than googling

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve same with **removeAll** API of collectionUtil.

```
list1.removeAll(list2);
```

Have a look at  [removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) API. It will remove all the elements from list1 which are present in list2. So in set theory it is ideally `A-B`